# tikzpicture without float numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, floating-point

I wanted to make a tikzpicture, that includes numbers. It looks like this:

[image]

My problem is, that I have no idea how to get rid of the .0 after every number. Can someone help me to get integers instead of floats?

Here is a short code snippet for the tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                % First Layer
                \edef\mya{0}
                \foreach \x in {0.5,1.25,...,4.25}{
                    \draw[] (0,\x - 0.5) rectangle (1.5,\x);
                    \pgfmathparse{\mya + 1}
                    \xdef\mya{\pgfmathresult}
                    \node[] at(0.75,\x-0.25){\mya};
                    \draw[->] (1.5,\x-0.25) -> (3,\x-0.25);
                }
            
                % Second Layer
                \edef\a{0}
                \edef\b{0}
                \foreach \x in {1.25,2.75,4.25}{
                    \draw[] (3,\x - 1.25) rectangle (4.5,\x);
                    \pgfmathparse{\b + 1}
                    \xdef\a{\pgfmathresult}
                    \pgfmathparse{\a + 1}
                    \xdef\b{\pgfmathresult}
                    \node[] at(3.75,\x-0.6333){[\a,\b]};
                    \draw[->] (4.5,\x-0.6333) -> (6.0,\x-0.6333);
                }
                
                \draw[] (6,0) rectangle (7.5, 4.25);
                \node[] at(6.75,2.1){[1.0,6.0]};
                
                \draw[] (-0.5, 2.85) rectangle (5, 4.75);
                \node[] at(1.25,4.5){Generalisierung};
                
                \draw[] (-0.5,4.75)rectangle (7.75, -0.5);
                \node[] at(6.75,4.5){Hierarchie};
                
                \node[] at(0.75,-0.25){Stufe 0};
                \node[] at(3.75,-0.25){Stufe 1};
                \node[] at(6.75,-0.25){Stufe 2};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `int`, as in `\pgfmathparse{int(\b + 1)}`, to convert the computed numbers to integers.

Comment: Oh well, that was simple :D Didn't know that, thank you!

Comment: You can also use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple. In pgfmath one can explicit typeconvert numbers, e.g. `\pgfmathparse{int(\b+1)}`. The resulting code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                % First Layer
                \edef\mya{0}
                \foreach \x in {0.5,1.25,...,4.25}{
                    \draw[] (0,\x - 0.5) rectangle (1.5,\x);
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\mya + 1)}
                    \xdef\mya{\pgfmathresult}
                    \node[] at(0.75,\x-0.25){\mya};
                    \draw[->] (1.5,\x-0.25) -> (3,\x-0.25);
                }
            
                % Second Layer
                \edef\a{0}
                \edef\b{0}
                \foreach \x in {1.25,2.75,4.25}{
                    \draw[] (3,\x - 1.25) rectangle (4.5,\x);
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\b + 1)}
                    \xdef\a{\pgfmathresult}
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\a + 1)}
                    \xdef\b{\pgfmathresult}
                    \node[] at(3.75,\x-0.6333){[\a,\b]};
                    \draw[->] (4.5,\x-0.6333) -> (6.0,\x-0.6333);
                }
                
                \draw[] (6,0) rectangle (7.5, 4.25);
                \node[] at(6.75,2.1){[1,6]};
                
                \draw[] (-0.5, 2.85) rectangle (5, 4.75);
                \node[] at(1.25,4.5){Generalisierung};
                
                \draw[] (-0.5,4.75)rectangle (7.75, -0.5);
                \node[] at(6.75,4.5){Hierarchie};
                
                \node[] at(0.75,-0.25){Stufe 0};
                \node[] at(3.75,-0.25){Stufe 1};
                \node[] at(6.75,-0.25){Stufe 2};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
\end{document}
```